# How to delete unnecessary spaces under the top tab bar?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm building a mobile app with `react-native` and `react-navigation`. 
However, there is an unnecessary area under the top tab, so I would like to ask about how to delete it.

This is the info about my app.

```
■ Library version
react-native: 0.60.08
react-navigation: 4.0.0

■ App screen structure
This app has one top tab navigator and one bottom tab navigator.

- The screens on the top tab
1. EventIndexScreen
2. EventAppliedScreen
3. EventCreatedScreen

- The screens on the bottom tab
1. Top tab navigator(EventIndexScreen, EventAppliedScreen, and EventCreatedScreen)
2. NotificationScreen
3. UserScreen
```

This is the screenshot of my app, I would like to delete the area inside red square.

https://gyazo.com/2816a387be1ba749d48b48df6b445117

These are my code.

- The code for top tab

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import EventScreen from '../components/screens/event';
import EventAppliedScreen from '../components/screens/event/EventAppliedScreen';
import EventCreatedScreen from '../components/screens/event/EventCreatedScreen';

const createTabStack = (title, screen) => createStackNavigator({
  [title]: { screen },
});

const topTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    EventIndexTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventTab', EventScreen) },
    EventAppliedTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventAppliedTab', EventAppliedScreen) },
    EventCreatedTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventCreatedTab', EventCreatedScreen) },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#333',
      inactiveTintColor: '#bbb',
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  },
);

export default topTabNavigator;
```

- The code for bottom tab

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import topTabNavigator from './TopTabNavigator';
import NotificationScreen from '../components/screens/NotificationScreen';
import UserScreen from '../components/screens/UserScreen';

const createTabStack = (title, screen) => createStackNavigator({
  [title]: { screen },
});

const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    EventTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventTab', topTabNavigator) },
    NotificationTab: { screen: createTabStack('NotificationTab', NotificationScreen) },
    UserTab: { screen: createTabStack('UserTab', UserScreen) },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#333',
      inactiveTintColor: '#bbb',
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  },
);

export default bottomTabNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **StackNavigator** has **"Navigation Header"** . The space is because of navigation header

**Please change this code**

```
{
    EventIndexTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventTab', EventScreen) },
    EventAppliedTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventAppliedTab', EventAppliedScreen) },
    EventCreatedTab: { screen: createTabStack('EventCreatedTab', EventCreatedScreen) },
  },
```

**To**

```
{
    EventIndexTab: { screen: EventScreen },
    EventAppliedTab: { screen: EventAppliedScreen },
    EventCreatedTab: { screen: EventCreatedScreen },
  },
```